Uppy + AWS S3 + Pre-signed URL (including metadata and tags). Uppy file upload failing with 'upload failed' and 'retry' error messages
getting this error while uploading image with awss3 uppy in angular 8.
can anyone send me solution of this error
[
i have added in tsconfig file lib set es2020
and i am using this link and script
and my uppy aws configration is in ts file

